# Java getting textfield value from different method

Tags: java, text, methods

I have two method, first method is to add in name and second method is to display out the name typed in pageone.

however how do I point to the textfield name to retrieve the input ?

```
public WizardPage pageone() {

    WizardPage page = new WizardPage("one", "page 1");

    JTextField name = new JTextField();
    field.setName("Name");
    page.add(new JLabel("Enter your name: "));
    page.add(name);

    return page;

}

    public WizardPage pagetwo() {
    WizardPage page = new WizardPage("two", "page 2");

    JTextField displayName = new JTextField();
    displayName.setName("displayName");
    page.add(new JLabel("Your name is "));
    page.add(displayName);

    return page;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `pagetTwo` must have a reference to the `name` `JTextField`. Declare the `name` variable as a field of the class, so you can read the field content in the `pagetTwo` method.

Something like this:

```
private JTextField name;

public WizardPage pageone() {

    WizardPage page = new WizardPage("one", "page 1");

    name = new JTextField();
    name.setName("Name");
    page.add(new JLabel("Enter your name: "));
    page.add(name);

    return page;

}

public WizardPage pagetwo() {
    WizardPage page = new WizardPage("two", "page 2");

    page.add(new JLabel("Your name is "));
    page.add(new JLabel(name.getText()));

    return page;

}
```

Comment: can give some example ?

Comment: JTextField name = new JTextField(); have to be on top ? What about having this still in the method?

Comment: If you'll have it in method, it's scope will be limited. It will not be accessible in `pagetwo();`

Answer (score 1):

As a good coding practice always do null check before assigning text value to pagetwo() so that it will not break the code even by mistake if you forgot to call pageone().

private JTextField name;

public WizardPage pageone() {

```
WizardPage page = new WizardPage("one", "page 1");

name = new JTextField();
name.setName("Name");
page.add(new JLabel("Enter your name: "));
page.add(name);

return page;
```

}

public WizardPage pagetwo() {
    WizardPage page = new WizardPage("two", "page 2");

```
page.add(new JLabel("Your name is "));
if(name != null){
   page.add(new JLabel(name.getText()));
} else {
   page.add(new JLabel(""));
}

return page;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

owh, in this case, u need to store the value from page one into a variable and just call the variable in method 2. unless u have nested method inside the pagetwo that will execute pageone method

```
String replaceName;

public WizardPage pageone() {

        WizardPage page = new WizardPage("one", "page 1");

        JTextField name = new JTextField();
        field.setName("Name");
        page.add(new JLabel("Enter your name: "));
        page.add(name);
    replaceName = name;


        return page;

    }

        public WizardPage pagetwo() {
        WizardPage page = new WizardPage("two", "page 2");

        JTextField displayName = new JTextField();
        displayName.setName("displayName");
        page.add(new JLabel("Your name is "));
        page.add(replaceName);

        return page;

    }
```

Comment: Why are u misguiding people? You cannot assign textfield object to string variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make the textfield as a reference object and not a local object. Declare JTextField as a reference object. i.e. `declare it outside the method or in a constructor`.

Comment: how to do it as a constructor

Comment: Declare it outside a constructor like-

`JTextField name;`

and initialise this in a constructor-

`name = new JTextField()`

I am sure it will solve your problem.